# Determine which of these relations are transitive. The variables x, y, x', y' represent integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A. x∼y if and only if x+y is even.
B. (x,y)∼(x′,y′) if and only if x−y=x′−y′.
C. x∼y if and only if x+y is positive.
D. x∼y if and only if xy≥0.
E. x∼y if and only if xy is positive.
F. x∼y if and only if x+y is odd.

I have A,B,D,E as my answers but it is incorrect. Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 1):

For D, $1 \sim 0$ and $0 \sim -1$ but $1 \not\sim -1$.

Comment: Can you please list your solutions i have tried 12 times i cant figure this out

Comment: Help??? please i need solution i have tried

Comment: @Zs11601 My answer is telling you that D is not transitive.